# Labels in TikZ are incorrectly interpreted

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm running into a weird problem with TikZ. The following code

```
\node (A) [label=45:$A$] at (p2) {};
```

is rendered correctly in one document, but incorrectly in another, larger document (which uses incidentally more packages, this is why I suspect some package clash.

Surprisingly, the label specified by the portion of the code `45:$A$` is rendered explicitly as 45:A, rather than being interpreted as A at 45°. There is no warning or error raised.

Any idea of where the problem might come from?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Do you compile the two documents on the same machine? Are are there potentially different versions of TikZ in play?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is actually due to a clash with the package `babel` (see the [manual](http://www.tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/babel/babel.pdf)). By using the command `\shorthandoff` before the tikz code, it works fine! For example, you could use:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}\shorthandoff{:}
[>=stealth']
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: So the problem is, I presume, due to the fact that the colon is being made active and so TikZ no longer sees it as a colon.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: I don't think it is the case anymore as of tikz-2.10.

Comment: Well, I was wrong in the comment above. This should now be fixed in the cvs version of tikz.

Comment: In version 2.10-1 (on Debian Wheezy), I'm still forced to comment out `\usepackage[myoptions]{babel}`. Well, it was worth a try.