# Test for a character, no matter if active or not (futurelet token)

Tags: conditionals, catcodes

I'd like to test for a character, irrespective its current catcode (i.e. active or not). This is very similar to [How do I test for a character, irrespective of catcode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29137/how-do-i-test-for-a-character-irrespective-of-catcode), however I cannot use `\pdf@strcmp` because I might have "half" macros (e.g. `\emph` without a parameter yet).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}% makes - active
\begin{document}
  \def\aaa{%
    \if a\noexpand\lookahead%
      (the letter a)%
    \else\if -\noexpand\lookahead%
      (a minus)%
    \else%
      (special treatment)
    \fi\fi%
  }
  \futurelet\lookahead\aaa -
  \futurelet\lookahead\aaa a
  \futurelet\lookahead\aaa \emph{c}
\end{document}
```

Changing catcodes before and after is not really a solution in my case, because the original meaning would get lost just by futurelet-looking at things.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have a look [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/27635) to know how to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\ifx` can be used for direct comparisons of the tokens. The following example stores the tokens in macros `\aaaHyphenActive` and `\aaaHyphenOther`. In the comparisons the hyphen tokens are unpacked via `\expandafter`.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}% makes - active

\begingroup
  \catcode`\-=\active
  \gdef\aaaHyphenActive{-}%
  \catcode`\-=12 %
  \gdef\aaaHyphenOther{-}%
\endgroup

\begin{document}
  \def\aaa{%
    \if a\noexpand\lookahead
      (the letter a)%
    \else\expandafter\ifx\aaaHyphenActive\lookahead
      (an active minus)%
    \else\expandafter\ifx\aaaHyphenOther\lookahead
      (a minus)%
    \else
      (special treatment)
    \fi\fi\fi
  }
  \futurelet\lookahead\aaa -
  \futurelet\lookahead\aaa a
  \futurelet\lookahead\aaa \emph{c}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expl3`. Here's a rough example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dosomething}{m}
 {
  \martin_do_something:n {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \martin_do_something:n #1
 {
  \peek_charcode:NTF a % test the first token against "a"
   {
    (the~letter~a)
   }
   {
    \peek_charcode:NTF - % test the first token against "-" (charcode only)
     {
      (a~hyphen)
     }
     {
      (special~treatment)
     }
   }
  #1
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\dosomething{abc}

\dosomething{-abc}

\dosomething{\emph{abc}}

\the\catcode`- % check that the hyphen was active

\catcode`-=12  % make it non active and try again

\dosomething{-abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]